# How to download file from django admin

Tags: python, django

I created *FileField* in *class Part* in *models.py*. Also I get the link of this file by method *file_link(self)*:

```
origin = models.FileField(upload_to='origin_files', null=True, blank=True)

    def file_link(self):
        try:
                return "<a href='%s'>download</a>" % (self.origin.url,)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            return "<a href=127.0.0.1:8000/main>download</a>"

    file_link.allow_tags = True
```

In admin.py I added *readonly_fields* for *file_link*. Also I added in fieldsets *file_link*:

```
readonly_fields = ('file_link',)

fieldsets = (
    ('Характеристики плёнки', {
        'fields': (....'data', 'origin', 'file_link')
    }),

)
```

So, in my django admin I have FileField which allows to upload files to directory *origin_files* and link to this file. But when I click on this link I'm redirecting to home page of my site. For example, I downloaded file presentation.pptx. When I get url of this file I get

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/description/part/12/change/origin_files/Presentation.pptx

How I can download this file?

Comment: There are a few strange things here. What is the point of that except block? That code could never raise PageNotAnInteger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure `MEDIA_URL` in your django settings

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#media-url

Django builds your url the following way:

settings.MEDIA_URL + "origin_files/Presentation.pptx"

the MEDIA_URL default is an empty string, therefore you get the url "origin_files/Presentation.pptx" and your browser concatenates it to the current page, because the url doesn't start with a slash.

so you have to set the MEDIA_URL for example to '/media/'

then everything will work in your development environment.

On remote server this also requires configuring the web server appropriatelly for it to serve your MEDIA_ROOT to MEDIA_URL (out of the scope of this question obviously).

Comment: hmm, in my settings.py there are not MEDIA_URL

Comment: @SBrain, I see - I updated the answer accordingly, (you must configure it), in brief: you can just set it to '/media/' to get it working.

Comment: It works. But to download this file I must add to urls.py 
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: @SBrain, you are right, thank you, but i’d suggest to do it inside of ‘if settings.DEBUG:’ clause and in production to serve the files with your web server means (as recommended by Django docs)