# How to download uploaded directory as a zip file from django admin?

Tags: python, django-admin, django-file-upload, django-admin-actions, directory-upload

I have uploaded directory using django and JavaScript. Now I am trying to download this directory from django admin. For this purpose I have followed this link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080257/how-to-show-download-link-for-attached-file-in-filefield-in-django-admin/41520310#41520310). When I have uploaded directory in django, the admin created the following table. File name indicates the uploaded folder name.

[image]

If I click on the file name, it shows me following error. I want to download this directory as a zip file from django admin. Can anyone please help me with this?

[image]

Here is my **model.py**:

```
class Prearchive(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/', null=True) 
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=500,primary_key=True)    
    file_id = models.ForeignKey(CreateScan, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1) 

    def _str_(self):
        return self.file_name
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CreateScan, Prearchive

# Register your models here.

class PrearchiveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model=Prearchive
    list_display = ('file_name','file_id','file_link')
    def file_link(self, obj):
        if obj.file:
            return "<a href='%s' download>Download</a>" % (obj.file.url,)
        else:
            return "No attachment"
    file_link.allow_tags = True
    file_link.short_description = 'File Download'

admin.site.register(Prearchive , PrearchiveAdmin)
```

**view.py:**

```
@login_required
def downloadScanView(request,url):
    print('url',url)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, url)
    zip_download = ZipFile(response, 'w',ZIP_DEFLATED)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        for root, dir, files in os.walk(file_path):
            print('r = ',root)
            for file in files:
                zip_download.write(os.path.join(root,file))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(os.path.basename(url)+'.zip')
        return response
```

Comment: Celery task to zip those files to a tmp location, then serve when the files ready by notifying in an email which expires in 24 hours and then delete those temp zipped files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is when I go into this url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/media/iit_0001_9_Unknown_aser4, I am having this 'Directory indexes are not allowed here.' error. I can not even see the files inside the directory. How can I get the files inside folder using this folder link?

Comment: You can't go to this url, because it's not defined within `django`, and the basic assumption is that if you are serving files for download you're doing that using s3 or a media storage backend.

Have you defined the media root in you `settings.py` folder?

Comment: I am using media storage backend and defined it in settings.py. This is in my setting.py: MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'). And I also set this (if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) ) in my url.py. I have modified my question and attached my download view code in there. Can you please explain me a bit about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening but the url I am getting is something like: /media/folder_name. My setting.MEDIA_ROOT is: /User/project/media. So when I try to use os.path.join(), it returns same path as url (/media/folder_name). It does not join the url with MEDIA_ROOT path.

Comment: Hi, it's working now. I tried to join absolute path with MEDIA_ROOT. That's why it could not find the file path properly. I took the base directory name from url and join with the MEDIA_ROOT. Now it's working. Hope I am doing it correctly. BTW, many thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Everything works as intended then? If not let me know what doesn't, I'm a bit daft.

Comment: Actually, it is only working when I call downloadScanView from the template. I can not download it from django admin panel. Could you please give me suggestion for this?

Comment: Yep, you need to use MEDIA_ROOT in `file_link` function as well. This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764746/how-to-download-file-from-django-admin

Comment: I have used it in file_link. No luck. It just shows the text '<a href='/users/project_name/media/folder_name' download>Download</a>' instead of creating any link.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view to download the file, and add urls.py entry for /media to this view.

views.py

```
def filedownload(request, filename):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile('download.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zf.write("media/" + filename)
    response = HttpResponse(zf, content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="download.zip"'
    return response
```

Main urls.py

```
path('media/', include('your_app.urls')
```

App urls.py

```
path("<filename>/", views.filezip, name="filedownload")
```

Comment: Can we do it this way? Where does the zipping actually take place? If it takes place on the server side, for typically large files won't it block the thread?

Comment: Ok I totally missed that you want to zip the files.